# How to close iOS app completely (wipe the RAM it uses) when switching to another app/homescreen

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native

I have a React Native app. When its not in the foreground it needs to be closed completely. The content of its memory must be gone and I would also like to wipe the cache.

Is this possible at all and if yes, how?

Comment: Nope not possible.  While it is possible to terminate an app you are strongly advised/told by Apple not to do it and it may get your app rejected.  You also have no control over how the apps are loaded/unloaded within the memory (RAM) of the device itself.  What reason have you got for doing it as there may be an alternative?

Comment: It is a business requirement because the app downloads parts of strongy restricted documents.  The customer requires that content is wiped completely from cache/RAM as soon as its not visible anymore. The app is going to be distributed only to company-managed devices.

Comment: The best you can do is to delete any versions of the documents you may have stored locally in the app and remove any controls that might hold reference to them when the app goes into the background.  Then decide what happens when the app comes back into the foreground (reload them, etc).  You don't have any control over what caching might have taken place internally by the system but there isn't really anyway anyone is going to be able to get access to them even if they are hanging around somewhere and they are only transient anyway.

Comment: You can make it to crash when it goes to background. But it can be rejected by Apple reviewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the info.plist key [`UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW23) to `true` then your app will be terminated when the user presses the home key rather than moving to the background.

> **UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend (Boolean - iOS)** Specifies that the app should be terminated rather than moved to the background when it is quit. Apps linked against iOS SDK 4.0 or later can include this key and set its value to YES to prevent being automatically opted-in to background execution and app suspension. When the value of this key is YES, the app is terminated and purged from memory instead of moved to the background. If this key is not present, or is set to NO, the app moves to the background as usual.

Any cache files that your app has created "on disk" will need to be deleted by your app in `applicationWillTerminate`.  Note that this method may not be called if the user terminates the app or the battery goes flat, so it is probably best to avoid persisting any sensitive data to disk.